# MS-WORD Special Character handled in Java/JSP

Tags: javascript, replace

MS Word uses characters from the Windows-1252 character encoding set which are not represented in ASCII or ISO-8859-1.

```
// smart single quotes and apostrophe
s = s.replace(/[\u2018|\u2019|\u201A]/g, "\'");
// smart double quotes
s = s.replace(/[\u201C|\u201D|\u201E]/g, "\"");
// ellipsis
s = s.replace(/\u2026/g, "...");
// dashes
s = s.replace(/[\u2013|\u2014]/g, "-");
// circumflex
s = s.replace(/\u02C6/g, "^");
// open angle bracket
s = s.replace(/\u2039/g, "<");
// close angle bracket
s = s.replace(/\u203A/g, ">");
// spaces
s = s.replace(/[\u02DC|\u00A0]/g, " ");
```

I used the REPLACE function before encoding to solve this issue. But I couldnt find the proper value for --> which gets converted into different format. Because of this issue, I got script error and leads to exception page.

Answer (score 0):

Actually left and right smart double quotes will have values 93 and 94 in hex.
So use these values instead of their Utf-8 values like 201C or 201D
eg

```
  str.replaceAll( "[\\u0093|\\u0094]", "\"" )
```